# Rule to allow folder in .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to "exclude" a directory (and all it's folder) from the rules in .htaccess file...

Not sure if that's possible?

The .htaccess file is like this:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
<Files ~ "\.(css|jpe?g|png|ico|gif|js)$">
Allow from all
</Files>
<Files "show.php">
allow from 127.0.0.1
</files>
```

Now, I want to exclude an entire sub-directory... 
from these rules...
i.e. Allow from all (for all file extensions in directory "SHOW-STR")

The only way now, is to do it file by file ... but I wonder if there's a way to exclude a sub-directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an htaccess file in your `SHOW-STR` directory with this:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
```

Comment: why didn't I think of THAT ^^^
all what I was thinking of is to add an exception to the parent folder's htaccess... but i guess it's way better to add the htaccess to the sub-directory.   Thanks again. :)